# jQuery slideToggle on a table

Tags: jquery, html

```
<table id="main_table">     
        <tr style="background-color:green; color:white">
            <td class="flip"> Section 1 </td>
        </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="section">
                <tr>
                    <td>item 111</td>
                    <td>item 112</td>
                    <td>item 113</td>
                    <td>item 114</td>
                </tr> 
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</table>

$('.flip').click(function() {
    $(this)
        .closest('table')
        .next('.section')
        .toggle('fast');
});
```

Can someone help me to correct above code
I tried slidetoggle but dunno why it is not working

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tr` instead of `table` to get the next row and use `find()` to get `.section`

```
$('.flip').click(function() {
    $(this)
        .closest('tr')
        .next('tr')
        .find('.section')
        .toggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: He changed the answer, anyway many people can give same answer with small difference of time

Answer (score 0):

the `section` element is a child of the next `tr` element

```
$('.flip').click(function() {
    $(this)
        .closest('tr').next()
        .find('.section')
        .toggle('fast');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XqBVL/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.flip').on('click',function() {
 $(this)
 .closest('tr').next('tr')
 .find('.section')
 .toggle(200);
});
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)